# Como configurar SVN corretamente

Tags: svn

Quero configurar o SVN em minha máquina para aprender mas estou tendo dificuldade, fiz a configuração corretamente conforme tutoriais na net mas o estranho é que ao acessar via navegador, não é requisitado usuário e senha.

Estou instalando em uma máquina virtual no Ubuntu.

Comment: Já tentou `apt-get install subversion`?

Comment: Ja sim, instalou corretamente

Comment: Você está instalando um cliente ou servidor?

Comment: @BrunoWego eu estava instalando e configurando um servidor SVN para acesso HTTP, mas já consegui, depois vou postar um tutorial de como instalar.